# Can't get the upload form in CodeIgniter to work properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have a form where a user can edit their public profile and upload a picture in the process. Everything works fine except for when a user has a photo uploaded or just leaves it blank to not change it it still goes ahead and tries to upload it and throws an error if it's empty... I do have a check in place, however it just ignores it.

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
        $file_name = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $img = $this->custom_lib->img_upload('./upload/user/', $file_name);
        $user_pic = 'upload/user/'.$file_name.$img['file_ext'];
    } else {
        $user_pic = 'upload/default.png';
    }
```

The problem I think is within the if statement however I don't see what it can possibly be. If I do select an image it uploads it just fine and everything works well. If I leave the image field blank (not select a file) instead of doing this:

```
$user_pic = 'upload/default.png';
```

it tries to upload a file... which doesn't exist... and then it throws an error. The img_upload() function is inside a custom library I made, however that function shouldn't even be called if no file was submitted.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

*isset* will return true even if the item you are checking contains nothing, is null, or is false.

To avoid this issue, you use *empty* like so:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']))
```

This will only return true if the $_FILES['userfile'] contains a value that is not null, false or empty.

Hope that helps :-).

Comment: I still get the same error, when I do print_r($_FILES['userfile']); it returns an array that says Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 )
How can I avoid this?

Comment: I ended up doing
    if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != '')
which fixed the problem... but how come the empty() function did not work? Any ideas?

Comment: You can also do if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) if that helps, my solution was mistaken as I forgot the errors could cause it to "not be empty". Apologies.

Comment: FYI from Offical Docs: *`isset()` will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL.*

Comment: That'll teach me to try and remember what functions do off the top of my head ;-)